# Print color mode and print flier size

Tags: color, cmyk, print-production, rgb, digital-printing

Am using coreldraw X7, so can I use RGB color mode for print fliers, CMYK is actually producing dull colors which I don't like and also what is the standard size (in inch) for print fliers...

Comment: What is a "flier"?

Comment: @Rafael - a leaflet, usually handed out to people in the street or stapled to notice boards, telegraph poles, stuck to night club exterior walls, subway tunnels etc… all a bit guerrilla. I've never noticed there's a standard size.. unless they're home made, in which case it's what ever size your average domestic printer will take - A4 or US letter etc. I very much doubt that accurate sRGB to CMYK conversion ever comes high on the priority list ;))

Comment: Depends on where you are getting fliers printed. Some print providers use RGB digital copiers essentially (mostly online providers). A commercial printing press is going to *require* CMYK color though. Everything printed gets converted to CMYK one way or another though. There are *many* RGB colors which *can't* be reproduced in CMYK.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was with an y. Flyer.

Comment: Can be spelled either way @Rafael -- at least in the US.

Comment: @Scott - and in the UK.